# error: cannot convert 'const char**' to 'const char (*)[64]'

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, arguments, implicit-conversion

I try to implement source code as below:

```
bool getParam(char* cmd, char** prm_arr, int num)
{
}

void main()
{
     char strC[] = "btOK,btCancel";
     char foo[10][10];
     bool res = getParam(strC,foo,2);
}
```

It shows error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘char (*)[10]’ to ‘char**’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘bool getParam(char*, char**, int)’
     bool res = getParam(strC,foo,2);
```

I think char** and char (*)[10] is similar in this case, isn't it?

Comment: An array is not a pointer, and a pointer is not an array. In particular, a pointer to an array is not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: If you could do this, the function could change `*prm_arr` to point somewhere else. But the thing being changed is 10 elements of a larger array; being able to "make it point somewhere else" makes no sense.

Comment: `char foo[10][10]` will allocate 100 chars arranged as 10 blocks of 10 chars each. It will not create an array of pointers to each block. Therefore you cannot get a pointer to a pointer array (`char **`). The solution depends on what you want to achieve. Do you need to pass two-dimensional arrays of variable size to `getParam()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array declared like

```
char foo[10][10];
```

is converted to the type `char( * )[10]` when is passed to the function. And there is no implicit conversion from the type `char ( * )[10]` to the type `char *`.

So the function declaration should be

```
bool getParam(char* cmd, char ( *prm_arr )[10], int num);
```

That is in expressions with rare exceptions arrays are converted to pointers to array elements type.

If you have an array of the type T as for example

```
T a[N];
```

when the array is converted to the type `T *`.

In the declaration of the array `foo` the type of its elements is `char[10]`. So the array is converted to pointer to the element type `char ( * )[10]`

Pay attention to that the function main shall be declared like

```
int main()
```

instead of

```
void main()
```

Comment: In case, I want to keep a function declaration of getParam. How can i pass foo into getParam(). Actually, foo is allocated dynamically base on type "cmd" command.

Comment: @ThaiDao For example you can allocate a dynamic array of pointers to char. char **p = new char *[10]; And then in a loop allocate arrays of the type char[10].